# Have a problem on how to set a default class

Tags: c++

In the `shape.cpp` I need set a default constructor for class `Point`, But I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

```
Point::Point(double _f, double _g){
    f = 1;
    g = 1;

}
Rectangle::Rectangle():Point(1, 1) {
    x = 1;
    y = 1;

}
Rectangle::Rectangle( Point q, double l, double w):x(l),y(w),Point(q) {
}
```

Comment: Use default arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point{
    int f,g;                           //declaring point(f,g)
    public :
    Point();                           //This will be your default constructor
    Point(double _f,double _g);        // Constructor for class Point
    int getf(){                        //just for purpose of display function() below. You can remove this once you understand code.
        return f;
    }
    int getg(){                        //just for purpose of display function() below. You can remove this once you understand code.
        return g;
    }
};

class Rectangle{
    double l,w;                         //declaring variable to store length and width of Rectangle
    Point pt;                           //whatever your use of point is
    public :
    Rectangle(Point q,double l,double w); //constructor for class Rectangle
    void display(){                     // displaying the class...just for demonstration
        cout<<"l = "<<l<<endl;
        cout<<"w = "<<w<<endl;
        cout<<"pt = ("<<pt.getf()<<", "<<pt.getg()<<")\n";
    }
};
//Defining the constructor of class Point 
Point::Point(double _f, double _g):f(_f),g(_g){}     // I have used initialiser list here           

Point::Point():f(0),g(0){}     // (your needed default constructor)    

Rectangle::Rectangle( Point q, double l, double w):l(l),w(w),pt(q) {} //Defining the constructor of class Rectangle

int main()
{   //Demonstrating object creation and displaying of object r of class rectangle 
    Point p(1,2);
    Rectangle r(p,5,10);
    r.display();
}
```

I have attached the code that would help you understand about **constructors** and **how to define** them.

Hope this solves your question !

Comment: Yes, there still have an error ' no default constructor exists for class "Point"  ' after pt(q)

Comment: Please check again. I have tried the above program and I am not getting any error. I have added the **default constructor** - `Point::Point():f(0),g(0){} `.

Comment: Are you checking the updated code? coz it's working just fine here! @OWGM. I have declared the default constructor `Point(); ` and also defined it as well - `Point::Point():f(0),g(0){} `.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Point{
    int f,g;
    public:
    Point();
};

Point::Point(){
    f = 1;
    g = 1;
}


int main(){
    Point *p = new Point() ;
}
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.